# SSL Configuration on WAS6

Tags: ssl, websphere

Our application is deployed on WebSphere Application Server 6. The application is mapped to the appserver instance so whether or not webserver is runnning, our application works fine. We have to run our application on https. Could someone please help me with the steps to do the same for the explained scenario? All the steps that i find in google tells configuring ssl w.r.t webserver.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are running WAS version 6.0 or 6.1 but here is the IBM documentation for SSL setup and other related topics:

- [WAS 6.0 - Securing communications](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/tsec_securecomm.html)
- [WAS 6.1 - Securing communications](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.nd.doc%2Finfo%2Fae%2Fae%2Ftsec_securecomm.html)